# I want to use match so that it will match for a perticular pattern having blank or space in between the pattern or on the starting of a word

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to use the Match so that I it can find for a pattern which contains blank also.
For ex- a = "this is me".
I want to search for "this is"
What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

The following is TRUE:

```
"this is me" BEGINS "this is"
"this is me" MATCHES "*this is*"
```

and when it's the content of a Database field that's used in a Word-Index

```
tablename.fieldname CONTAINS "this is"
```